# How to strengthen employees' identity feeling in the company?

Tags: work-environment, company-culture, employer-relations

What methods do you use to strengthen employees identity "feeling" in the company they work at? Every company has its own values and it is described what company's identity is. It is quite a challenge for HR department to figure out how to involve employees in everyday work while letting they feel that they are a part of company's identity. What are your thoughts on that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**First and formost, pay them at or above the market value for their professions. No one will ever identify with a company that is a wage thief.**

Next, value their input. That means listen to their concerns and take action on them. When people are telling you there is a problem and you don't listen, they shut down.

Don't shoot the messenger. No one will tell you bad news if you blame them for bringing it up.

Promote from within. If managers always come from outside, it is a bad sign.

Don't micromanage. Give people some flexibility in how they do things.

HR can't fix this problem by themselves, it is mostly a management problem when people are dis-engaged.

Answer (score 8):

[Gallup's Q12](https://christopherfeld.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/gallups-12-questions-to-measure-employee-engagement/) has some questions that may be a good starting point:

> 1. Do I know what is expected of me at work?
> 2. Do I have the materials and equipment I need to do my work right?
> 3. At work, do I have the opportunity to do what I do best every day?
> 4. In the last seven days, have I received recognition or praise for doing good work?
> 5. Does my supervisor, or someone at work, seem to care about me as a person?
> 6. Is there someone at work who encourages my development?
> 7. At work, do my opinions seem to count?
> 8. Does the mission/purpose of my company make me feel my job is important?
> 9. Are my co-workers committed to doing quality work?
> 10. Do I have a best friend at work?
> 11. In the last six months, has someone at work talked to me about my progress?
> 12. This last year, have I had opportunities at work to learn and grow?

Consider how does your company help employees answer these questions in a positive way. Do you show you care, does employees befriend each other, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried asking your employees? What most of us want most (well, after some of the essentials others have mentioned) is to know that our opinions and actions and contributions are listened to, taken seriously, and appreciated... and asking them and acting on their input would be a good start in that direction.